# Struts 2 action method not invoked upon form submission

Tags: javascript, struts2

```
function test() {
    var obj = document.createElement("FORM");
    obj.action="SomeAction!thisMethod.action";
    obj.submit();
}
```

However, the action method is not invoked at all.

Action mappings look good in `struts.xml` but just in case you're wondering,

```xml
<action name="SomeAction" class="com.test.SomeAction">
    <result ...>...</result>
</action>
```

It's working fine if I have a Struts2 form on that page, but when there's no forms and I want to invoke the action method with a dummy form object, it does not work.

I feel like I'm missing something in the form object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a newly baked form to the `body` of `document` before invoking `submit()`.

```javascript
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

---

In Struts2 `s:form` the attributes are auto generated. You don't need every of those attributes to submit the form with dummy form element.

If you use jQuery you can do

```javascript
$("<form>", {    
    "action": "SomeAction!thisMethod.action"
}).appendTo(document.body).submit();
```